# Mongooperations add/remove json into MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongotemplate

I am having JSON structure like this :

{

```
"prodinfo": {
             "memberid": "m1",
             "user":{
                     "userid":"001",
                     "product":{
                                "productname": ["pname1"],
                                "productid": ["p1"]     
                               }
                     }
             }
```

}

for a given memberid , it can have mutiple userid and a userid can have mutiple product.productname , product.productid in a array. I should able to perform add and remove to this document in the same fashion.
I tried to implement same using Mongooperations (springframwork data) to persists the document in the MongoDB. But I am unable to do the fashion.
Can somebody guide me how to achieve this using Mongooperations/Mongotemplate of springframework data?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not according to your structure it cannot. JSON and therefore BSON ( which is actually what MongoDB uses for storage and not JSON ) can only have a singular occurance of a given key and not "multiple" ones as you claim. To do so requires an "array" or "List" structure, which is different from the "Hash/Map" structure you describe here. I suggest you are not notating correctly as to what your real structure is.

Comment: @BlakesSeven , I am trying to do "for a given memberid , it can have mutiple userid and a userid can have mutiple product.productname , product.productid in a array. I should able to perform add and remove to this document in the same fashion" and for this I thought the JSON structure mentioned above, I might be wrong as I am new to mongodb. Kindly suggest what is the structure should be ?

Comment: You are wrong because the structure mentioned above contains no arrays even though you keep mentioning arrays. If this is your structure then it is incorrect. Or alternately this is not your actual structure and you need to alter your question to show the correct structure.

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
@Document
public class prodinfo{
private String memberid;
privare List<User> user;

// getter and setter
}

public class User
{
private String userId;
private Product product;

// getter and setter
}


public class product
{
private List<String> productname;
private List<String> productid;

// getter and setter
}
```

As per your explaination, Here One memberId has Multiple User and user has product which contains multiple productID and productName for specific userID.

Comment: Thanks @nirajdarji , actually I can able to design the entity class based on the JSON structure , but problem I am facing I am not able to persists the data in the fashion where for a given memeberid there can be mutiple userid and for a userid there can be mutiple product.productname and product.productid(which will be list structure). Every time I set the values and do mongooperations.upsert() , it overwrites .

Comment: my code:
`Query query= new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("user.userID").is(userID).andOperator(Criteria.where(memberid).is(memberid)));     
Update update = new Update();
update.set("memberid",memeberID);
update.set("user.userid",userID);
update.set("user.product.productid",productID);
update.set("user.product.productName",productname);
mongoOperations.upsert(query, update, ProdInfo.class);`

Comment: I think the way you want to persist the data by your structure was wrong. You want to persist multiple data for some field so you need array or list for that.